# Is it possible to get PathPattern as a Bean in the SpringBoot web and reuse it in user code?

Tags: spring-boot, reactor-netty

Is it possible to get PathPattern in the SpringBoot web as a Bean and reuse it in user code?

For example, if the url is : `/user/1990/lily`, it return the url patten on the Controller: `/user/{year}/{name}`.

[This](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc) said:

> Patterns are parsed on startup and re-used at runtime for efficient
> URL matching

[Reactor-netty metrics](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/1.0.0-RC2/reference/index.html#_metrics_4) need a `uriTagValue` to avoid cardinality explosion,

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Metrics.globalRegistry 
               .config()
               .meterFilter(MeterFilter.maximumAllowableTags("reactor.netty.http.server", "URI", 100, MeterFilter.deny()));

        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()
                          .metrics(true, s -> {   // HERE is the uriTagValue, it's a smaple of how to handle url mapping.
                              if (s.startsWith("/stream/")) { 
                                  return "/stream/{n}";
                              }
                              else if (s.startsWith("/bytes/")) {
                                  return "/bytes/{n}";
                              }
                              return s;
                          }) 
                          .route(r ->
                              r.get("/stream/{n}",
                                   (req, res) -> res.sendString(Mono.just(req.param("n"))))
                               .get("/bytes/{n}",
                                   (req, res) -> res.sendString(Mono.just(req.param("n")))))
                          .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
              .block();
    }
}
```

Config the Netty to enable metrics in a SpringBoot WebFlux app:

```
@Configuration
public class NettyWebServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReactiveWebServerFactory reactiveWebServerFactory() {
        NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory = new NettyReactiveWebServerFactory();
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> httpServer
            .wiretap(true)
            .metrics(true, s -> "") // enable metrics, ignore all uri, if SpringBoot Web expose URI-Match-Patterns as Bean, we can use it here.
        );

        return factory;
    }
}
```

My wondering is that is it possible to get PathPattern as a Bean in the SpringBoot web and reuse it in reactor-netty metrics code? As simmple as: `bestPattern.matchAndExtract(lookupPath)`

I tested `PathContainer.parsePath(s);`, it seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With this setup, you are not using Spring WebFlux but actually Reactor Netty directly. `PathContainer` and `PathPattern` are then irrevelant here.

I don't think reactor-netty is storing anywhere the matching `UriPathTemplate` when considering the `HttpPredicate`.

Comment: I update my question. It is using Spring WebFlux with a Reactor Netty as an component.

Comment: My comment still stands. The route definition DSL you are using is pure reactor Netty and Spring WebFlux is not involved here.

Comment: If patterns are parsed on startup and re-used at runtime, Netty server can reuse them.  Reactor Netty and Spring WebFlux are in one java application.

Comment: What I mean here is that the `HttpServer.route(...)` DSL you are using is reactor-netty only, no Spring is involved here. You can use this setup outside of a Spring application. The Spring web frameworks are not involved in this case.

Comment: The piece of code  related to `HttpServer.route(...)` is just a reference. My app is a SpringBoot WebFlux. Actually, I want to reuse the functionality of PathPattern

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, which tends to make my posts quite laborious... (sorry about that)